# Groovy: How to execute sh commands extracted from jenkins "build with parameters"

Tags: bash, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

In my pipeline, I have a parameter that allows the user to input bash command(s). My goal is to basically execute these commands through this pipeline's groovy script at a certain point in the stage.

The solution that I've come up with so far is to create an sh file, write the inputted bash commands to that file, then execute it. The following code is able to accomplish what I want **but only if the user inputs a single bash command**.

```
sh """
touch BEHAVE_EXTRA.sh
echo ${params.BEHAVE_EXTRA} > BEHAVE_EXTRA.sh
bash ./BEHAVE_EXTRA.sh
"""
```

If I put multiple bash commands in the Jenkins parameter, the sh file is not properly executed and the pipeline fails.

Is there a way to accomplish what I need through with bash, or should I use groovy code/methods only? In either case, how can I go about solving my problem? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the parameter type for BEHAVE_EXTRA?
You will have to use 'text' there for multi-line.

See here

```
pipeline{
agent any

parameters {
    text (defaultValue: '',
            description: 'Enter your Commands Here',
            name: 'BEHAVE_EXTRA')

}

stages {
    stage ('Bash from File'){
        steps{
            cleanWs()
            sh '''
                touch BEHAVE_EXTRA.sh
                echo "#!/bin/bash" > BEHAVE_EXTRA.sh
                echo "${BEHAVE_EXTRA}" >> BEHAVE_EXTRA.sh
                chmod 755 BEHAVE_EXTRA.sh
            '''
            sh "./BEHAVE_EXTRA.sh"
        }
    }
}
```

}